# asp label text changed event in Jquery

Tags: jquery

How to trigger a jquerymethod when the value of an asp label changes?
I have tried this one but it's not working.

```
 $("#lbladdsupplier").change(function () {
        alert('Changed');
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `change` event is fired only when an form elements value is changed.

In this case I would suggest to trigger a custom event when the label is text updated.

Ex:

```
$("#lbladdsupplier").html('new-label').trigger('labelchanged')

$("#lbladdsupplier").on('labelchanged', function(){
    alert.log('changed')
})
```

Comment: awesome! exactly what I was looking for.