# label changed event on click on button in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

**I wants to fire label change event**

I have a label. I wants to fire change event after click on button

I have code of jQuery as bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var count = 1;
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            $("#Label1").text(count++);
        });
        $("#Label1").on('labelchanged', function(){
                alert("Values is changes");
            });
    });
```

My HTML is as bellow:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click" />
        <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

label change event is not fire in my code

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314627/asp-label-text-changed-event-in-jquery post

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/Ln1zu69q/1/

Answer (score 2):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ueonq1wu/)

```
var count = 1;
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $("#Label1").text(count++);
    $('#Label1').change();
});

$('#Label1').on('change', function (e) {

    alert("we");
});
```

ON click event trigger the on change manually

Comment: In this case change event is fired even value not change. if I will not increment "count" variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a method who doesn't exist (`labelchanged`). Try this instead :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 1;
    var labelValue = $("#Label1").text();

    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $("#Label1").text(count++);
        if ($("#Label1").text() != labelValue) {
            alert("Values is changes");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @osama_1200 Is my solution helped you ?